# How can I do this without changing css and just use html?

Tags: html

I used the feversocial platform for easy web design, one of which is to make changes directly with code, but the effect I want is to make changes to CSS, I asked the company, and they only allow us to make changes with HTML, so CSS cannot be used, may I ask how to shorten the upper and lower ends of the vertical line?

Now I only make vertical lines with hr, and I tried hr style and div style, but I still can't shorten the top and bottom ends.

Thank you all for your help.

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Vau.png)

[Want to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KR2sG.jpg)
This one was altered in Photoshop.

[feversocial code view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qT9Y.png)

[hr style and div style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6i39.png)

```
<hr style="filter:alpha(opacity=30,finishopacity=30,style=5);height:150px;width:2px;" color="orange">

<div style="width:1px;border:1px solid gray;float:left;height:600px;">
</div>
```

Comment: No, you can't, because HTML is only markup language, without any visualization. Everything that you see in that page is made with CSS, either it's default browser CSS or custom.

Comment: The best you could do Is using a <table>, but it will not look as "smooth" as your pics

Answer (score 1):

You could use in-line css. If the company says you can only use HTML, then they clearly do not know how HTML works (no offence).

But if they are really really opposed to having any .css files, you can use the inline `style` param to do styling within the .HTML

It's really not recommended, but if you have to, you should

Example:

```html
<p style="color: Red">Hello</p>
```

All the css can work inline.

also, since im not sure how you made the vertical line, I can't help you there, maybe include the code for the page instead of just the image.

Comment: It's still considered css

Comment: yeah idk what this management is on saying "no css" but its not editing a css file so maybe they won't care/

Comment: It depends. If you read between lines, the company doesn't want to allow changes in CSS files, which can be explained by the fact that it could ruin the whole website look. If it's the case, this answer is valid, as would be one using `<style>` tag in `<head>`.

Comment: yeah, that was my intention here